# How to replace specific string in data frame column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, deep-learning

I have `input.txt` file that has 2 columns (`file_name,text`) and want to replace "   "  seprater charchter (which represnt  tab here becuse I spreated txt file by this char) that apperar in `text` column

example for input file :

```
0.jpg   Jól olvasom?   Összesen négy, azaz 4   számot játszott   el 
1.jpg   a csapat a   koncerten  Ilyet még nem is hallottam
```

I wrote the following code :

```
df = pd.read_csv(f'{path}labels.txt',# labels labels_tab_remove
                 header=None,
                 delimiter='   ',
                 encoding="utf8",
                 engine='python'
                 )
df.rename(columns={0: "file_name", 1: "text"}, inplace=True)
print(df.head())
```

So I want to replace "  " tab by " " single space

```
for idx in range(len(df)):
 df['text'][idx].replace("   "," ")
```

So the expacted output :

```
0.jpg   Jól olvasom? Összesen négy, azaz 4 számot játszott el 
1.jpg   a csapat a koncerten Ilyet még nem is hallottam
```

Comment: You could use `df['text'][idx].split().join(' ')` I reckon.

Comment: Can't you do something like `df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace("  ", "")`  ... no need for renaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need Pandas to do that?

```
import re

with (open('labels.txt', encoding='utf-8') as fp1,
      open('labels_clean.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as fp2):
    for row in fp1:
        if row.strip():
            file_text, text = re.split(r'\s{3}', row, maxsplit=1)
            text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text)
            fp2.write(f"{file_text}{' ':4}{text}\n")
```

Content of `labels_clean.txt`:

```
0.jpg    Jól olvasom? Összesen négy, azaz 4 számot játszott el 
1.jpg    a csapat a koncerten Ilyet még nem is hallottam
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all comments before.As [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75643822/how-to-replace-specific-string-in-data-frame-column-value/75644079#75644079)  mention we do not really need pandas we can use it after process text

```
import pandas as pd
import json
CLEAN_TEXT = True
path= './'
if CLEAN_TEXT:
    import re
    with open(f'{path}labels.txt', encoding='utf-8') as fp1:
     with open(f'{path}labels_clean.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as fp2:
        for row in fp1:
            if row.strip():
                file_text, text = re.split(r'\s{3}', row, maxsplit=1)
                text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text)
                fp2.write(f"{file_text}{' ':4}{text}\n")

df = pd.read_csv(f'{path}labels_clean.txt', # labels labels_tab_remove 
                 header=None,
                 delimiter='   ',
                 encoding="utf8",                 
                 engine='python',
                 ) 
df.rename(columns={0: "file_name", 1: "text"}, inplace=True)
print(df.head())
```